# order by date field when datatype is nvarchar

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005, join

With one of the answers on stack I have used following query:

```
select 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , 
  AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) AS sauda_date,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     
  SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword 
from tradefile 
where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'
  and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' 
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) order by CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date) desc
```

This query gives me output below:

[image]

In this if we look at sauda_date column, after 28 Feb 2013 it is ordering it by 22 Mar 2013 , then 21 Mar 2013 then 20 Mar 2013 , etc.

But it should be 28 Feb 2013 , 1 Mar 2013 , 2 Mar 2013 .... , 20 Mar 2013 , 21 Mar 2013 , 22 Mar 2013.

What changes I should make in query?

**Note:** sauda_date is of nvarchar type

**NEW QUERY:**

```
select AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate , AVG(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGSellRate,  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, sauda_date, 106), 106) as Sauda_Date,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "',106) and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "',106) THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty ,     SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) -SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 and scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS CarryForword from tradefile where scrip_code='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString() + "' and INST_TYPE LIKE 'FUT%' group by convert(datetime,sauda_date,106) order by convert(datetime,sauda_date,106) desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```
select
  ....,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, sauda_date, 106), 106)
...
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, sauda_date, 106), 106)
order by CONVERT(DATETIME, sauda_date, 106) asc
```

Also you need the lowest date first, so i believe you need an `asc` and not a `desc`

Comment: Column 'tradefile.Sauda_Date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: lozz... I am sorry can give only 1 upvote, if it was in my hands, i would have given you thousands of...thanx for answer.

Comment: but, there is one more isue, its not giving me avg and sums, its showing me all records, should i make changes to Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "') THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS AVGBuyRate

Comment: edited? it still shows the same code...`CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),sauda_date)`

Comment: i suggest you to check the `group by` once again...keep it the same as in the `SELECT` clause - `CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, sauda_date, 106), 106)`

Answer (score 4):

You're converting the date to text for sorting, so you get the text order. "F" comes before "M". Without knowing the schema I'd say: try removing the `CONVERT...` call from `ORDER BY` clause.

Also it seems you want `ASC` order, not `DESC`.

Edit: You say sauda_date is `nvarchar` type. I'd say that either it shouldn't be (use a proper date type for storage), or you'll have to convert it back to datetime for sorting.

Comment: I have sauda_date is of nvarchar, and 28 Feb 2013 comes first thats ok, but after that sequence of date should start from 1 Mar 2013 but its starting from 22 Mar 2013, 21 Mar 2013